# Why does the next method in Random use a compareAndSet?

Tags: java, random, atomic

While reading through the documentation for the java.util.Random class in Java, I stumbled upon something inside the `next` method that I couldn't quite get my head around.

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

I noticed the use of `!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed)`, and I'm trying to understand what it's there for. What is the explanation?

Comment: Do you know what that method does, in general? That is, are you asking what it is, or why it's specifically needed here?

Comment: @yshavit I do know what `compareAndSet` does, or what it's used for in general, yes, just not what its use is in this `next` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [JavaDoc for compareAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#compareAndSet(long,%20long)):

> Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current value == the expected value.

This is done to make sure that between the `seed.get()` and the set (inside the comapreAndSet), no other thread has called another `set()` (e.g. by a parallel call of `next()`). Because the old seed is used to calculate the next seed. If in between an other Thread would have called the `seed.set()` method the "next" seed would not be calculated with the latest value. The value before the last value would have been used and the algorithem would have side effects in a multi threaded environment.

This algorithm is used to be thread save. Because if the old value is not the expected one, the loop will be repeated until both values match.

Comment: Actually another `set()`.

Comment: So it's a way of ensuring that if 2 threads call the method `next()` at the (approximately) same time, it does not generate 2 equal pseudorandom numbers?

Comment: yes, both threads get always different numbers (if they get the same it is the result of the "random" generator and not of the concurrent call at the same time)